# How to check if node has one or more specific attributes with XPath in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to get every child node which contains one of the these attributes: type, ref, base. The value of each attribute doesn't matter, I just want to check if the attribute exists.

This is how I do it now:

```
private void addRequiredNodeAndChildren(Node n) {    
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression = "*//*[@base or @ref or @type]";
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression);
            NodeList referList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(n, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            ..
}
```

This expression works fine but in one case I don't get all expected nodes:

```
 <xs:complexType name="ListElement">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:attribute name="transferMode" type="myprefix:dataTransferMode"
            use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Documentation for attribute
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I expect to get the  node with the expression above, but unfortunately I don't get it. Change the expression to

```
//*[@base or @ref or @type]
```

didn't help either, as a result of that I got every node from the XML with one of the attributes but I want to get only the child nodes of the given node n. I also tried

```
*//*[@base] or *//*[@ref] or *//*[@type]
```

as expression but that didn't work as well.

Has anyone ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: the * in front of the xpath is unneeded and makes no difference, but as an xpath it works fine, assuming the namespaces xs and myprefix are defined. Presumably your document had other things in that did work? What do you mean by 'only the child nodes of the given node n? Do you mean you got the annotation? with the child documentation(documentation for attribute)?

Comment: The prefixes are defined and everywhere else in the document this solutions works fine. With "only the child nodes of the given node n" I meant that I want to look for the attributes only in the "xs:annotation" node and the "xs:attribute" node.

Comment: You don't say exactly which wanted node you isn't selected. Please, clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help!

I found a solution which is not very pretty but at least it works:

```
*[@base or @ref or @type] | *//*[@base or @ref or @type]
```

EDIT: I adapted [Dimitre Novatchev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) solution, which solves the problem too:

```
descendant-or-self::*[@base or @ref or @type]
```

Answer (score 0):

> `//*[@base or @ref or @type]` 
>   didn't help either, as a result of that I got every node from the XML with one of the attributes but I want to get only the child nodes of the given node n

That's because '//' searches the whole document. Your predicate is correct, but the sequence you are filtering is wrong. To get the children of the context node, use

```
*[@base or @ref or @type]
```

Incidentally, if you're trying to list all the attributes in XSD that contain QNames referring to other declarations in the schema, your list is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but editing the sequence didn't solve my problem, with this filter other nodes have been ignored too...

Which other attributes can be used to refer to other declarations?

Comment: Well, I've already said that if I were designing the application I wouldn't do it this way, so I don't think I'm going to guide you down a route that I wouldn't take myself. Processing schema documents is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is:

```
*[descendant-or-self::*[@base or @ref or @type] ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but this expression didn't solve my problem as well

Comment: I changed your solution to 
`descendant-or-self::*[@base or @ref or @type]` and it works fine